# Data storage suggestions

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure

My very first post on this forum but I have a problem with choosing how to store the data that my website will generate.

Its a project I'm working on for my boss and its a Time/Project management tool written in ASP.NET

The system is supposed to track the amount of work hours each person spends on a project and store this data for a minimum of 3 years, Now I was thinking of going with SQL but I'm having doubts when it comes to fetching older data further ahead and with queries taking too long.

About 2500 entries per month with starting and ending time, the id of the person and an id for the project they have been working on.

What would be the best solution here?

Right now it's supposed to be for the company only but might go public further ahead and in that case would the same solution still hold?

Using Azure for hosting.

Thank you

Comment: SQL databases can handle data far in excess of 2500 entries per month.  Don't hesitate to design a solution using a database, if that is your main worry.

Comment: That was quick :) So no problem with fetching older data either?

Comment: Timing for Fetching of data would be depending on the way you write SQL queries and not databases. SQL would be a good solution.

Comment: Alrighty then, I'll give it a go then. Thx for the quick responses.

Comment: I'll concur. I have 80 employees and over 16 years in my version

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, and we are not here to recommend a storage system to you. We're for answering specific programming problems.

Comment: @KevinK - Not sure why you marked Tobias' answer as accepted. There's no right answer to this question. *Any* database will work for your app. We have no idea of your schema, your query patterns, your reporting tools... nothing. Plus you have a very small amount of data. Even 3 years of data, at 2500 per month, is less than 100K entries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A SQL database can handle millions of entries without a problem, don't worry about that. If performance issues should occur you could take a look at sql index, a way to improve lookup speed for a certain column, e.g. matching a name like in a nvarchar (..) column.

Any other storage solution is probably a lot slower and less maintainable in the future, especially since you need to store your data up to three years

---

Edit 1:

Also, like mentioned in the comments;

> NoSQL database like Azure Table Storage / CosmosDB can perform very
>   well as well

That said, any database like approach will probably work.

Comment: "Any other storage solution is probably a lot slower and less maintainable in the future" -> why is that? a NoSQL database like Azure Table Storage / CosmosDB can perform very well as well. Without proper info about the schema the OP has in mind you cannot tell.

Comment: @PeterBons that is indeed true, with "other storage solution" i was talking more about storing information in files or something like that. I guess any database approach is acceptable

Comment: @PeterBons updated my answer